# File's owner thinking it is superclass

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, xib

Something very strange is going on with my interface builder. So I created an `NSWindowController` subclass in Xcode, with the create XIB option enabled. I started coding, and I successfully connected to file's owner.

But, when I run my app, I get the error :

```
Failed to connect (workspaceControl) outlet from (NSWindowController) to (NSSegmentedControl): missing setter or instance variable
Failed to connect (workspaceField) outlet from (NSWindowController) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
Could not connect action, target class NSWindowController does not respond to -changeNumberOfWorkspaces:
```

I don't know why this error is showing up as I have my code set up right:

[image: working code]

And the File's owner is set to the right class (AddController):

[image: file's owner]

So why does it try to connect my views to `NSWindowController` instead of my subclass?

EDIT:

Where I actually use the AddController in code:

`AppDelegate.h`

[image: appdelegate.h]

`AppDelegate.m`

[image: appdelegate.m]

It's in appdelegate because it is a menubar app. (In case anyone was wondering)

Comment: Have your tried to recreate nib totally?

Comment: Have you tried a clean build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the actual object that is instantiated in your running program is an `NSWindowController`, not an `AddController`.  You've shown us that `AddController` is properly declared, and you've shown us that your nib's File's Owner is set to `AddController`; that's great, and is why you don't get a compile-time warning or error about things being wired up incorrectly.  But you haven't shown us where the controller object actually gets instantiated; and examining that would presumably reveal that it hasn't been changed to `AddController`.  So at runtime you've got an `NSWindowController`, in violation of what you promised to IB would be the case; and so you get runtime errors.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code in app delegate.

Comment: Oh ma gad. I just did cmd - f and typed nswindowcontroller. I found that a couple days agao I was testing the xib and had set up `NSWindowController` and showed the window. Wow. I feel like I wasted everyones time.